# How install Angular2 Webpack Starter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I try to start [Angular2 Webpack Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)
Node v6.3.1
NPM v3.10.6

Step by step:

```
# clone our repo
# --depth 1 removes all but one .git commit history
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git

# change directory to our repo
cd angular2-webpack-starter

# install the repo with npm
npm install
```

And when I try run: **npm start**
The latest lines in command window:

```
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
[default] Checking started in a separate process...
[default] Ok, 6.164 sec.
```

nothing else happens, help me

Comment: Open browser and go to http://0.0.0.0:3000 or http://localhost:3000

Comment: yes. something opened. but it is looks like broken. redirected to http://localhost:3000/%3C%=%20webpackConfig.metadata.baseUrl%20%%3E#/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try (first) a more simple angular2 webpack starter like for example:

https://github.com/schempy/angular2-typescript-webpack

Comment: This is a suggestion, not an answer.